# ASP.NET MVC design issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view with 2 partial views (a gridview and a callback panel)

This main view receives a `IEnumerable<Model>` and the panel just receives a `Model`.

When the view is initially called, the partial view of the panel is filled with an empty model so it is empty.

But I want to re render the panel once I click `Edit` in my GridView.

How can I achieve this?

I currently have an `@Html.ActionLink` in the Edit button but its not working since it will create a new view instead of re render the partial view of the panel.

Any clues?

EDIT:

this is my Edit:

```
Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditConfig", new { id = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "QueueMonitorConfigurationsID") })
```

Function that the edit link calls:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditConfig(int id)
    {
        StorageConfigurationModel resultForPanel = new StorageConfigurationModel { };
        IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel> configList = (IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel>)Session["ConfigurationList"];
        foreach (StorageConfigurationModel configModel in configList)
        {
            if (configModel.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID == id)
            {
                resultForPanel = configModel;
                break;
            }
        }
        return PartialView("cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs", resultForPanel);
    }
```

Main view containing the partial views:

```
@model IEnumerable<BPM.Website.Models.StorageConfigurationModel>

@Html.Partial("gvConfigurations", Model)

@Html.Partial("cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs", new BPM.Website.Models.StorageConfigurationModel { QueueMonitorConfigurationsID = -1 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with an `Ajax POST`

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

Answer (score 4):

> I currently have an @Html.ActionLink in the Edit button

You could use AJAX. For example you could replace this `Html.ActionLink` with an `Ajax.ActionLink` and include the `jquery.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` scripts (in that order) to make it act as an AJAX call. For example:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "click to edit record", 
    "Edit", 
    new { id = item.Id }, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "editContainer" }
)
```

When the link is clicked the Edit controller action will be invoked using an AJAX request and the id of the current item will be passed as parameter. When this AJAX request completes a DOM element with `id="editContainer"` will be updated with the results of this AJAX call. So your Edit controller action should return a partial view containing the record to be edited.

Comment: How can I pass the parameter then? In my case I pass an `id` so I know the Model id I have to display

Comment: You would simply pass the id of the record to be edited as part of the routeValues parameter to the Ajax.ActionLink helper as shown in my answer. Since you will have an Edit link for each record you already know the id of the record. The Ajax.ActionLink will then generate an url with the following format: `/somecontroller/edit/123` where `123` is of course the id of the record to be edited. And your Edit controller action will simply take this `id` parameter as argument.

Comment: This is doing exactly the same. Maybe the funcion I call is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *it's doing the same*? Do you know the difference between `Ajax.ActionLink` and `Html.ActionLink`? Do you know what AJAX is? Also in the code example you have shown you seem to be using some `DataBinder.Eval`. Do you know the difference between classic ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC? You seem to be completely confusing what ASP.NET MVC is. I would recommend you reading some very basic getting started tutorials here: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Yes @Darin, I know. But it is an action link, and the way it is, it wont rerender the partialview I want. Maybe my issue is the function it calls.